# How to create postgres table in talend using create query

Tags: postgresql, talend

i am trying to create table in talend using below code i see no error but in database this table is not getting created
`do $$ declare begin execute  'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tname';      execute  'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tname (ACTIVITY VARCHAR(32))'; end $$ ;`

Please help me i am new in Talend

Comment: did you try using tDBRow component ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be something like this

```
DO
$$ 
DECLARE BEGIN 
    EXECUTE  'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tname';      
    EXECUTE  'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tname (ACTIVITY VARCHAR(32))'; 
END; 
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to just use this component **tDBRow**

[image]

And a very important thing is to to use  tDBCommit after the tDBRow if not the table would not be created in your Postgres Database
or just tick the commit (in advanced settings  if you are using tDBConnection component)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you soo much it work  using above suggestions

Comment: Could you mark topic as solved if it helped